# Tailwind and storybook setup postcss config issue

Tags: javascript, storybook, tailwind-css

I have the following postccs.config.js file:

```
module.exports = {
    plugins: [
        require("postcss-import"),
        require("tailwindcss"),
        require("autoprefixer"),
    ],
}
```

which allows me to run tailwind and storybook together, however when I try to run my application, I get this error:

```
Error: A PostCSS Plugin was passed as a function using require(), but it must be provided as a string.
```

Is there a way to provide a specific storybook postcss config or even a better way for the 2 to work with the same config?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to execute the require.
Your config should look like this:

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    require('postcss-import')(),
    require('tailwindcss')('./tailwind.config.js'), //This refers to your tailwind config
    require('autoprefixer'),
  ],
};
```

also this was answered before @see: [How to configure VueJS + PostCss + Tailwind with Storybook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53027576/how-to-configure-vuejs-postcss-tailwind-with-storybook)

Comment: It doesn't solve the issue, storybook runs fine but the not the application.

Comment: Do you still get the same Error ? 